# How would I combine a tuple of tuples into a single tuple?

Tags: python, list, apache-spark, tuples, rdd

I am joining three RDD's in spark by chaining joins:
`joined_rdds = rdd1.join(rdd2).join(rdd3)`

the output of joined_rdds.collect() is:

```
[(key, (([list1], [list2]), ([list3]))), 
(key, (([list1], [list2]), ([list3]))),
...]
```

**how do I transform that output to**:
`[(key, ([list1], [list2], [list3])), (key, ([list1,] [list2], [list3])), ...]`?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out a workaround, but this will not be ideal for bigger joins:

```
joined_rdds = rdd1.fullOuterJoin(rdd2).fullOuterJoin(rdd3)

combined_tuples= joined_rdds.map(lambda x: (x[0], (x[1][0][0], x[1][0][1], x[1][1])))
```